# Determine if executable file has any .net dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

I would like to determine whether or not a file has any dependencies to the .net framework. The catch: I want to do this *without* the use of any third party application.

I was hoping there was some hidden method in existence that I could use for this.

Thanks for any help,
Evan

Comment: By virtue of being c# I think it has .net as a dependency

Comment: Outside of any additional context, A "file" doesn't have a dependency to anything. Are you referring to determining whether a .dll or .exe is native versus .NET?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, I'm sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I will be loading VB6 executables, C# executables etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(
      pathToAssembly);
   AssemblyName [] an = 
      a.GetReferencedAssemblies();
   foreach (AssemblyName name in an) 
      Console.WriteLine(name.ToString());
```

... Courtesy of [Determining .NET Assembly and Method References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163641.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that this code will not work with native files... which is what I need it to do.

Comment: I will use this code, and if an error appears I will know it was not written in .net. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A .NET executable has special fields in its header that you can look for, but even native EXEs can implicitly rely on .NET, say by invoking a COM service that's written in .NET.

Comment: I see, so I'll need to look into the PE header to find this information?

Answer (score 0):

By nature, a C# application will most likely link against the standard C# libraries. If you are talking about another library, outside of the standard libraries, I don't know if that is possible. What exactly do you mean by 'third party' in this situation?

Comment: There are companies that make products for things like this. I didn't want to have to use that, i wanted to do it through code.